# How I use/clean this old SIGG bottle that makes water taste bad?

Tags: reuse

In my furnished apartment I found a 0.6 litres SIGG bottle from unknown year and previous tenant.

It makes the water taste bad (not clearly a metallic taste, somewhat different or more in addition to that) and also I found out that old SIGG bottles release BPA: http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/news/2011/07/some-aluminum-water-bottles-still-contain-bpa/index.htm

Supposing I decide not to use it anymore due to taste and/or BPA, any idea how to put it to use? I don't like to throw it away but the small opening does not allow many uses.

Since BPA may not be a real issue
https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/is-bpa-in-can-linings-a-health-concern
how could I clean it?

Additional information:

- in the cap there is a "4" between a tilted "C" letter and a standard PP symbol. Maybe from 2004?
- the SIGG logo seems different from the current bottles, see photo
- the internal surface is lined with a golden material, see photo
- to clean the inside and to test the thermal insulation I filled it with some boiling water mixed with dish soap and rinsed very well
- the water still tastes strange when I tried it, after the cleaning

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Sustainability SE! I think only your 'alternative use' question is on-topic here. Whether it's safe probably fits better on Health SE and how to clean on Outdoors SE.

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.treehugger.com/green-food/sigg-bottles-now-bpa-free-but-what-were-they-before.html#14705989834461) the golden linings are the old ones that contain traces of BPA. I know there are [cleaning tablets for SIGG bottles](https://sigg.com/bottle-accessories/bottle-clean-tablets-20pcs-bottle), but I'm not sure if they contain anything special.

Comment: @THelper I rewrote the main question without deleting the original data, in case they can be useful for searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't meant to be a complete answer, but since it sounds like there's a chance you might keep using the bottle, and you convince yourself it's safe, it might also be worthwhile to confirm the strange taste you've noticed is from the bottle. You could simply try comparing the taste with water from another container, or take a scientific approach...

1. Store some water in the bottle for a reasonable period of time in conditions that are similar to how you might use the bottle (ie a few hours, perhaps a day, at room temperature), and store some water from the same water source at the same time in another container known not to affect flavour (eg a glass bottle, with a lid), ensuring both containers have been well washed and rinsed.
2. Pour an equal serving into 2 identical cups/glasses/bottles that have also been well washed and rinsed at the same time. Label each vessel with it's source (SIGG or control, but it's best if you can't see the labels)
3. Get a friend to reposition the containers such that you don't know which is which (ie the labels aren't visible)
4. Try water from each container and see which tastes best, then check the labels

Also bear in mind that our brains tend to blend taste and smell senses together, so if the bottle has a particular smell that may affect your perception of the taste.

Comment: I left some water on it for a day. The bad taste is definitely gone after cleaning with dish soap and vinegar. I taste something metallic now but I don't know if it's the feeling of the lips on the metal of the water itself. I will pour the water in a separate glass and compare with other water (stored for the same amount of time in a glass or plastic bottle) as you recommended to avoid bias. In fact, I think the SIGG bottle may be usable after all.

Comment: @OlafM also consider the possibility that using the bottle after it's been stored unused for many days may bring out a flavour depending on materials used in the product. Even storing the bottle in location that has a particular smell may make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use it for drinks, you could use it for storing fuel. eg for a camping stove.

Though it would be a good idea to take some precautions for this. First make sure it doesn't leak at all, and no signs corrosion or other damage.

It depends on what sort of fuel you want to store. Methylated spirits can corrode aluminium, so it should not be used for that. But petrol/gasoline or white gas (Coleman fuel) would be OK. The standard O-ring seal on the cap could be damaged by petrol, but you can get a replacement O-ring made of nitrile rubber, which would be safe.

Also probably best not to use for a stove that pressurises the bottle, as it may not strong enough for that. Bottles for pressurised fuel should have thicker walls.

And a good idea to clearly label the bottle, so you know it has fuel in it, and prevent confusion with a drinks bottle.

Comment: It's a long time since I looked into this, but some fuels could apparently dissolve (some of) the coating on water Siggs. My fuel Siggs are uncoated. Dissolved plastic might not be a good idea to burn, for the sake of your stove jet if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

To clean it I suggest home-brew steriliser or baby bottle steriliser. If that doesn't fix the bad smell/taste, I wouldn't use it for drinks and would probably recycle the metal (unless you want it for an unusual vase).